# can't insert from php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create group and topics in this group but i don't know why i can't insert the form.

I use 2 sessions - first one from category to groups and second one from groups to group and 1 session is for user

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../_database/database.php';
if(isset( $_POST['topic_button'] )){
    $top_name = $_POST['top_name'];
    $top_about = $_POST['top_about'];
    $top_pic= $_POST['top_pic'];
    $groid =$_GET['gro'];
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics (top_name, top_about, top_pic, top_date, Groups_gro_id, users_user_id, categories_cat_id) VALUES ('$top_name', '$top_about', '$top_pic', 'NOW())','$groid', '".$_SESSION['username']."','".$row['categories_cat_id']."')");

    header("Location: ../home.php");
}
?>

<form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="components/ins_topic.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="title " name="top_name">
        </div>                     
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="post here" name="top_about"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="top_pic" class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in"  type="file"/>
        </div>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="topic_button" data-style="zoom-in" >post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`gro` is session like that in link `"group.php?gro=1"`

Does anyone know why can't i insert from form?

Comment: You should check for errors from `mysql_query()`, and then use `die(mysql_error())` if it fails. Then you'll see the reason why it didn't insert.

Comment: You also need to prevent SQL injection. See the first **Linked** question.

Comment: you are inserting 'NOW())' extra bracket

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is some mistakes because closing brackets`)`. Try this:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics (top_name, top_about, top_pic, top_date, Groups_gro_id, users_user_id, categories_cat_id) VALUES ('$top_name', '$top_about', '$top_pic', 'NOW()','$groid', '".$_SESSION['username']."','".$row['categories_cat_id']."')");
```

Try to use `Mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment this line:

```
//header("Location: ../home.php");
```

Then it should tell you what error is when you submit form. Also, turn on error mode:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```